# Size of element resizes when it shouldn't

Tags: css, meteor, typeahead.js, typeahead

I have this package installed and working well all except the css. I want it to look like any other text field until you click and start typing.  However the size of the box is not behaving.  When I remove all the width information in the css from the example code this does not help. I was hoping it would become a normal size text field and match in with my others.

I do though see for a very brief second that it does display full width then re-renders or shrinks down to a smaller size.  I am not sure what I am missing here.

Html Call

```
<input class="form-control typeahead clearForm box-size" name="customerSearch" type="text"
               placeholder="Customer Search:" autofocus="on"
               autocomplete="off" spellcheck="off" data-open="open" data-close="close" 
               data-select="select" data-autocomplete="autocomplete"
               data-source="customersTypeAhead"/>
```

CSS

```
/* basic typeahead styles */
.box-size{
  height: 23px; 
}

.typeahead,
.tt-query,
.tt-hint {

  padding: 8px 12px;
  line-height: 23px;
  border: 2px solid #ccc;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
      border-radius: 5px;
  outline: none;
}

.typeahead {
  background-color: #fff;
}

.typeahead:focus {
  border: 2px solid #0097cf;
}

.tt-query {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
     -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
          box-shadow: inset 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.075);
}

.tt-hint {
  color: #999
}

.tt-menu {

  margin: 4px 0;
  padding: 8px 0;
  background-color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
       border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
   -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
      box-shadow: 0 5px 10px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
}

.tt-suggestion {
  padding: 3px 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  line-height: 24px;
}

.tt-suggestion:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0097cf;
}

.tt-suggestion.tt-cursor {
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #0097cf;

}

.tt-suggestion p {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Picture of what it looks like

[image]

What I would like is for it to be the same width as the other boxes which have no set width on them.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a little old, but I had the same issue today. After dissecting the example files, .js and .css I found it. You and I both were doing the same thing, we missed the very last css statement which makes the width (in my case) bootstrap friendly that the demo app does not have...

Add this to your css declarations and it should work:

```
.twitter-typeahead {
   width: 100%;
}
```

That did the trick for me. Hope you found it before now!

Comment: Very nice. Just tried it. Works like a charm. Thank you so much for sharing.